# Confused on how to authenticate with Flickr API

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, flickr

I have a private photoset on flickr
I want to use the API to authenticate myself so I can retrieve my photoset .. ok, so far so good ...
BUT ... i'm getting really confused because the recommended way to authenticate is to use [oauth](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html), but as far as I understand oauth (and the flickr documentation) it allows user to connect their flickr account to my web application ... BUT that's not what I want ! I simply want to connect to flickr API with MY account and retrieve MY data ... i'm struggling with this since this morning ... I simply don't understand how to authenticate with an API call (without having to provide callback URL, user interaction, etc)

Thanks

Comment: for example, if I want to use https://github.com/rezzza/flickr I've already got API key but how can I obtain oauth access tokens ?
`$metadata->setOauthAccess('access token', 'access token secret');`

Answer (score 1):

You'd just need to [create an app on Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/) that is private only to you. Then you'll have the consumer key and secret which you can use to authenticate yourself to your app, and then interact with your Flickr account.